# Badge counts are cropped when there are too many badges

Tags: bug, answers, badges

My issue is this: Jon Skeet's 6715 bronze badges are shown as 671, and part of the 5 is cut off.

[image: A disservice to Jon Skeet.]

It seems that for someone of Jon Skeet's stature, the badge numbers get cut off since the user profile image/name/badge counts are displayed at the same location regardless of total pixel size.

This is a great disservice to the great Skeet, as he cannot proudly display his plethora of bronze badges while this injustice continues.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Dang. I always seem to end up asking duplicates, because I'm not searching for the right terms.

Comment: No problem. Here's a bonus link: [Jon Skeet Facts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134/246262)